# Compare two html files on another html page

Tags: html, file, compare

I am working on a intranet project that allows our companies web authors to edit the content of our internet site. I am currently trying to get a rollback feature to work. I currently show the current content and backup content code side by side on the page so the author can see what will happen if they do a backup. I was wondering if there was some sort of comparer (or easy way of implementing one) that will highlight the differences between the html code of the two files.

Thanks

Comment: You do realise that any files served on a production server should be read only?  Maybe you permit one directory to be writable for file uploads but that should be it.  Your "web authors" should be able to pull down a copy of the live files, edit them locally, then push them back up through sftp or some similarly secure method.

Comment: Both files being compared are on the intranet. When a page gets published to the live site there is a copy on the test server and on the live server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Resig implemented a nice algorithm for isolating differences between files in javascript, which can be found [here](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/).